# what does smooth/soft probablity mean?

Tags: deep-learning

I was recently reading the `Knowledge Distillation` paper, and encountered the term `smooth probabilities`. The term was used to denote when the logits were divided a temperature. 
[image]

> Neural networks typically produce class probabilities by using a
>   `softmax` output layer that converts the logit, `zi`, computed for
>   each class into a probability, `qi`, by comparing `zi` with the other
>   logits where `T` is a temperature that is normally set to 1. Using a
>   higher value for `T` produces a softer probability distribution over
>   classes.

What does that mean intuitively?

Comment: It means that the distribution is made less 'spiky', or accentuated. It will be readily apparent if you take a random set of input logits and visualize it yourself. This distribution originates from statistical mechanics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution

Answer (score 7):

When $T$ gets larger, i.e. $$T \rightarrow \infty $$ the probability distribution resembles the uniform distribution, so $q_i = \frac{1}{n}$. You can find the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57434/boltzmann-soft-max-distribution), as well as some other interesting properties.

Given the previously mentioned fact, I guess he is referring to [smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing)  in the sense that the noise if left out and what remains are the important patterns of the data, that is the distribution is made less 'spiky' as @Emre mentioned.